# Print Barcode on pdf using JsPdf in Angular js

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, pdf

I was implemented Barcode in html but we can't print barcode on pdf. Because of I think it was make barcode css is dynamically and apply on it. So, We can't get up Barcode css on JsPdf.

Below Code using I Displaying Barcode on Html.
(Using barcode Generator Directive )

```
    <div id='thing'>
        <div barcode-generator="0123" style="height:50px;" ></div>
    </div>  
<!-- language: lang-js -->

    var printDoc = new jsPDF(); 
    printDoc.fromHTML(($('#thing').get(0)), 10, 10, {'width': 180}); 
    printDoc.autoPrint();
    printDoc.output("dataurlnewwindow");
```

Using Javascript I try to Print Barcode Portion Can't displaying. so, If you want to any suggestion or advice then help me. Thank you....

Comment: i had the same problem, you can use jspdf and jsbarcode, here is a plunk https://plnkr.co/edit/uWyBhqX4wb0nD5PQ2Jvd?p=info hope it solves ur problem

Comment: Sorry, It's not Working Properly and thanks for help.

Comment: oh i am sorry, i had added a wrong plunker please make use of this one https://plnkr.co/edit/UgJZwiUzVLS4ni1E4P66?p=preview

Comment: Hey ! Gaurav i want in angular js . your link is good but it's in ajax.